# Find $F(n)$ if $F(n)=2F([\frac{n}{2}])+2$ for $n>2$ and $F(2)=1$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, analysis, elementary-number-theory

Find $F(n)$ if $F(n)=2F([\frac{n}{2}])+2$  for $n>2$ and $F(2)=1$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$[\frac{n}{2}]$ mean the largest integer does not exceed $\frac{n}{2}$

Approach: I only conduct one relation which is $F(2k)=F(2k+1)$ for $k=1,2,3,...$, then I try to use telescoping summation to cancel term but fail. Anyone has some idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "nearest" integer is ambiguous. It seems you want the ceiling function ...

Comment: "nearest" means the round function, relative of floor and ceiling functions.

Comment: You are right,sir, when $n=\dfrac{2m+1}{2}$. However calculators for the "round function" gives for half positive odd integer the value of floor function. If you take both, floor and ceiling you lost something desired in some contexts (an indirect proof of this would be that calculators admit the round function, besides of floor and ceiling ones of course. Sorry for English).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a way to address it:

$F(2^1) = 2$

$F(2^2) = 2\cdot 2 + 2$

$F(2^3) = 2\cdot(2\cdot 2 + 2) + 2$

$F(2^m) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}{2^k}$

Now you can do the proper variable transformation: $ [\frac{\log{n}}{\log{2}}]$ so:

$F(n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{[\frac{\log{n}}{\log{2}}]}{2^k}$

Comment: amazing! Never thought in this way. I guess the remaining part will be checking the formula for n>2.

Comment: I have not checked, honestly. But I do believe if it is not right, minor adjustment would be necessary.  Please let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I am working on checking if it is valid for the n>2 case. Need to deal with the nearest integer of some logarithm

Answer (score 0):

First at all $$\left[\frac{2m+1}{2}\right]=\left[\frac{2m+2}{2}\right]=m+1$$ Therefore $$F(2m+1)=F(2m+2)=2F(m+1)+2$$ It follows
$$F(2)=1\\F(3)=F(4)=2F(2)+2=4\\--------------------\\F(5)=F(6)=2F(3)+2=10\\F(7)=F(8)=2F(4)+2=10\\--------------------\\F(9)=F(10)=2F(5)+2=22\\F(11)=F(12)=2F(6)+2=22\\F(13)=F(14)=2F(7)+2=22\\F(15)=F(16)=2F(8)+2=22\\--------------------\\F(17)=F(18)=2F(9)+2=46\\F(19)=F(20)=2F(10)+2=46\\..................\\F(31)=F(32)=2F(16)+2=46\\--------------------\\F(33)=F(34)=\cdots\cdots=F(64)=2F(17)+2=94$$ 
We see $F$ is defined to be constant on each interval $I_n=[2^n+1,\space 2^{n+1}]$.

One has $$F(2^n+1)=F(2^n+2)=\cdots=F(2^{n+1})=2^{n+1}+2^n-2$$

In other words, the $2^n$ integer values in the interval $I_n=[2^n+1,\space 2^{n+1}]$ have the same image by $F$ which is equal to $2^{n+1}+2^n-2$. This defines completely the function knowing that $F(2)=1$.

**NOTE**.-The function $F$ is the restriction to $\mathbb N$ of a step function that can be represented analytically using the characteristic function $\chi_I(x)$ defined by
$$\chi_I(x)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if } x\in I\\ 0\text{ if } x\notin I\end{cases}$$

We can do, partially on each interval $I_n$, $$\color{red}{F(m)=\chi_{I_n}(m)\cdot(2^{n+1}+2^n-2)\text{ where }\space I_n=[2^n+1,\space 2^{n+1}]}$$ or totally, taking the restriction to $\mathbb N$ of the function $F$ defined over $\mathbb R$ which is
$$F(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1,2\}}\chi_{I_n}(x)\cdot(2^{n+1}+2^n-2)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using characteristic function is convenient but I am still looking for a 'neat' form of the solution by just using floor function

Comment: You are welcome. Anyway I add that everything in the NOTE is an appendix of, say, "mathematical culture". The function $F$ is completely determined before the aforementioned NOTE if you read more carefully. my answer. I mean,any way to calculate it should result in the same $F$.

Comment: I guess there is an issue in your solution since F(2)=F(3)=1 and all the latter follow.  But your idea still valid